# How to split big switch statement

Tags: c++, networking

I'm making an online game and when I receive data from a client, i receive several 'structures' ( say 'my position', 'use potion 23', 'attack player 45', 'talk bla bla', logout,  etc.), those structures are read securely and put into structs, pushed on a list and (later on, when the server has time) processed.

The thing is that the processing is a Big switch statement (switch on a sort of enum-"RTTI") and I have over 60 different structs which are all different.

So the .cpp containing the processing code starts to get fairly big and it won't shrink any time as I constantly add functionalities to the game (the c++ is somewhere between 4000-5000 lines).

I can see a simple solution to this, each case calls a function in another file but that will literally (note to harriyott, yes literally as my project and my drive will be flooded with new files) explode the number of files I need to know and keep track of.

I know I can cut it up (the cases) in several fileN.cpp and make '#include "file1.cpp" #include "file2.cpp" etc. in the processing file but that seems horribly wrong.
And any other way that I have 'thought up' to circumvent this problem seems way too 'hacky'.

So the question is, **how do you split up a big switch statement nicely?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can

- replace the switch with a mapping from the enums to handler functions (the function implementations themselves can be in the same file, or in different files, as you prefer), or
- (the more object oriented solution) make all the structs in question inherit from a common interface declaring a handler method, make each implement the desired functionality in its specific handler method, then call them polymorphically.

Comment: Is that some C++0x stuff or can you do that easily in 'standard' c++ (Windows + Linux)?

Comment: "inherit from a common interface" yes that will let me stock say 10 classes in each .cpp so it will be easy to write but not very nice to read :-)

Comment: @Valmond, which one you are asking? Anyway, you can implement either of these using plain standard C++ features.

Comment: @Valmond, you already have your 60+ `struct`s defined somewhere don't you? All you need is add a new function to each.

Comment: "All you need is add a new function to each." true but (and I fell this is the only way, hence the question) then I have to stock them off in any weird way (say in 1 file or in a hundred, one .h/.cpp for each).

Comment: @Valmond, well, **you can't make complexity disappear**. If you deal with a complex problem, the program solving it will have that complexity encoded somewhere within. You can put it in one big heap here, or separate it into many smaller heaps over there, you can make it dense or sparse, but you can't make it go away, just change its shape and form. The only thing you can do is to find the simplest and most intuitive structure that incorporates all the complexity you have.

Comment: You're right of course, just wanted a (possible) solution in between the one I have and splitting up everything. Seems there are no one. +1 & solved

Answer (score 1):

By using [map_list_of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#map_list_of). Something like this :

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual ~Base(){}
  virtual void foo()=0;
};
class D1 : public Base
{
  virtual void foo() { /*1*/ };
};
class D2 : public Base
{
  virtual void foo() { /*2*/ };
};

Base* Lookup( const int v )
{
  const static map< int,Base* > next = map_list_of( 1,new D1)(5,new D2);
  return next[v];
}
```

Comment: I need code to be executed depending on the RTTI, this will just translate an integer into a string, right?

Comment: @Valmond Ok, I adjusted the example for RTTI. The previous example was supposed to be simpler and demonstrate how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that boost::variant could make your life easier. You build your main event type as a boost::variant of classes and then use static_visitor classes to do your magic. Essentially a switch, but wrapped nicely and type-safely in logic.

Comment: I hate variants as much as I love Boost and I can't see why this won't leave me with either 1 big file or hundreds of smaller...

Answer (score 1):

Why not go for another approach where you have a map (hashmap) with message id as key mapped to handlers. Each handler handles a single message.

The processing would then just do a lookup based on the incoming message (id) and call the found handler.

Comment: "The processing would then just do a lookup based on the incoming message" That is what I'm doing already, hence the (big) switch state.

Comment: Sure, but you have a very long function. A lookup and call of handle is just a few lines and you can have handlers in own classes. Nicer than include "some.cpp". If you want to have a switch, then this is of course not interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an class with an abstract function, say `process`. Instead of structs create the appropriate class. Then instead of the `switch` all you need to do is call the `process`` function for the element on the list.

Comment: same as above, 1 file with everything or hundred of files ... or say 5 files in .h/.cpp 1, 20 in .h/.cpp B etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use Object Oriented approach, use the select ONLY to select the appropriate class. The design will be more flexible, and it will pay off later when you will add more actions, objects or whatever.

> i receive several 'structures' ( say 'my position', 'use potion 23',
>   'attack player 45', 'talk bla bla', logout, etc.),

You can already spot some exemplary classes: like `GameObject` for all potions, etc, or `GameActor` for player and monsters. Later, you can have some `GameAction` class that can accept "source" and "destination" of the action, like Axe and Ogre. You can have `UseAction` or `AttackAction` inheriting from `GameAction`, with `setSourceOfAction(obj)`, `setDestinationOfActon(o)` and `doAction()` methods.

At the end you won't need th bloated `switch()` at all, or maybe to select through a few of the base classes. I think this is the way.